# Printing only parts of a hash

Tags: perl

So I have a hash in perl setup that has multiple values for each field, i used this to push data into the hash:
 `push  @{$user{$infoName}}, $information;`. 
eg. a user my have 3 favourite shows all stored as

```
{'favourite_TV_shows' => [ 'A Country Practice', 'All Saints', 'Falling Skies' ], 'weight' => [ '53kg' ]}
```

Some of this user info is private such as weight so the fields i want to show are stored in the array `@fieldsToPrint = ['username','favourite_TV_shows']`

how can i write a foreach loop to print only the fields that are in the feildsToPrint array.
The following is my attempt so far...

```
foreach ($user{$infoName} == @fieldsToPrint){
   #print
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate on your `@fieldsToPrint` array, skipping those keys that don't have a value:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @fieldsToPrint = ( 'username', 'favourite_TV_shows' );

my %user = (
    'favourite_TV_shows' => [ 'A Country Practice', 'All Saints', 'Falling Skies' ],
    'weight'             => ['53kg'],
);

for my $key (@fieldsToPrint) {
    next if !$user{$key};
    print "$key = ", join(', ', @{ $user{$key} }), "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
favourite_TV_shows = A Country Practice, All Saints, Falling Skies
```